# GoogleMock Eq: не вызывается оператор сравнения класса

Tags: c++, google-mock

У меня есть такой код:

```
class Money
{

};

class Dollar : public Money
{
public:
    Dollar(int amount);
    Dollar times(int value);
    bool operator==(const Dollar& dollar);

    int amount;
};

Dollar::Dollar(int amount)
    : amount(amount)
{

}

Dollar Dollar::times(int value)
{
    return Dollar(amount * value);
}

bool Dollar::operator==(const Dollar& dollar)
{
    return amount == dollar.amount;
}
```

Я хочу его протестировать, используя GoogleMock:

```
#include <gmock\gmock.h>

using ::testing::Eq;

TEST(Money, TestDollarMultiplication)
{
    Dollar five(5);
    Dollar product = five.times(2);
    ASSERT_THAT(product.amount, Eq(10));
    product = five.times(3);
    ASSERT_THAT(product.amount, Eq(15));
}
```

Этот тест работает, но я хочу сделать его чистым и написать как-то так:

```
TEST(Money, TestDollarMultiplication)
{
    Dollar five(5);
    Dollar product = five.times(2);
    ASSERT_THAT(product, Eq(Dollar(10)));
}
```

или

```
ASSERT_THAT(five.times(2), Eq(Dollar(10)));
```

Обратите внимание, что в `Eq(Dollar(10))` передается r-value.

Этот код не компилируется:

> error C2678: бинарный "==": не найден оператор, принимающий левый
>   операнд типа "const Dollar" (или приемлемое преобразование
>   отсутствует)

Мне предлагают посмотреть во внутренности библиотеки:

```
namespace internal {

struct AnyEq {
  template <typename A, typename B>
  bool operator()(const A& a, const B& b) const { return a == b; }
};
```

В чем здесь проблема и как ее исправить?

Answer (score 0):

У вашего оператора сравнения отсутствует `const` квалификатор (как и у функции `times`).

```
bool operator==(const Dollar& dollar) const;

bool Dollar::operator==(const Dollar& dollar) const
{
    return amount == dollar.amount;
}
```

И не забывается про `const` квалификатор для переменных, при его использовании проблема бы вскрылась раньше:

```
const Dollar five(5);
```

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что лучше всегда делать метода константными, чем иметь две версии метода - const и не const?

Comment: @typemoon Не совсем, наличие или отсутствие `const` определяется предназначением метода. Если он должен изменять объект - то `const` не нужен, если он не должен изменять объект, то `const` нужен.